# knowing next value from auto increment field mysql java

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I want to know the next value of auto increment field
I wanted to test this :

```
select max(contactid) from contact
```

and I add 1
but I realized that it can give me an error
for exemple
if I insert one record and I delete it
so if I insert after the field will increase by two

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If your goal is to 'predict' a generated id, don't. This **always** leads to trouble sooner or later.

Comment: There is no reliable way to predict the next AUTO_INCREMENT value that will be assigned to a row inserted by the current session. The closest you can get is a `LOCK TABLE` and a `SHOW TABLE STATUS` statement, but even then, do not design your code to be reliant on predicting an auto_increment value, because that code will be "broken" by design, even though simple test cases may make it appear  to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem:

**1. (Preferable) Stop trying to predict auto-increment values**

This is the more typical case, and basically is using auto-increment as designed. This assumes that you don't actually need the auto-increment value *before* you insert. What you can do is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment, x INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO t (x) VALUES (100);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The call to `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` will return the ID that was just generated for your `INSERT`.

**2. Set up an ID generation table specifically to generate IDs**

You can create a table with just an auto-increment column, like so:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS id_generator;
CREATE TABLE id_generator (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

You can then generate a new, unique ID with:

```
INSERT INTO id_generator (id) VALUES (NULL);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

And use that ID to insert into the table you're actually working with. As long as all generated IDs come from this ID generation table, there will be no conflicts. However there is a cost to generating these IDs, and auto-increment is not very efficient at it.

**3. Use an external ID generation scheme**

This is more or less similar to solution 2, but doesn't use MySQL at all for the ID generation. You can use something like a UUID/GUID scheme which generates a string, or you could use something like [Snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake) to generate integer IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LAST_INSERT_ID` like this:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

It will return the last value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID field.

More details here: http://goo.gl/RkmR5

Comment: That's an oversimplified description of the value returned by the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. And the syntax of that statement is invalid... the LAST_INSERT_ID() is a function, the parens are required. Also, there is no need to return that value for every row in the `contact` table.  The function will return the value for the latest INSERT, whether or not a row was inserted into the `contact` table.

Comment: thank you spencer. that was 3am when I've been writing it. Will fix it now

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the *next* id value that *will be* inserted:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1;
```

Comment: No, it won't. If you've just `INSERT`ed a row, it will give you the auto-increment value assigned to that row, plus one.

Comment: @jeremycole you are incorrect: It return the value last inserted ( as the name of the function suggests). From the mysql doc: `LAST_INSERT_ID()`: *Value of the AUTOINCREMENT column for the last INSERT*. See [the official mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for full details.

Comment: No, this does not necessarily give the next id value that will be inserted... if the session has not performed an INSERT statement that generate an autoincrement value; or if the statement inserted more than one row; if the AUTO_INCREMENT column is not the leading column in an index on a MyISAM table, or if the auto_increment_increment variable is set to a value other than 1, if another session generates an AUTO_INCREMENT value in the table... there are all manner of conditions where this statement will not reliably return the next AUTO_INCREMENT value to be generated, let alone inserted.

Comment: @Bohemian The text you quoted agrees with me. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give you the ID of the row you last inserted. `+ 1` (in your answer) will add one to that. That is **not** the same as the "next value that will be inserted"; the value returned may even have already been used by another session. In any case this is not a safe way to get the "next value" (hint: there isn't one).